# Tangent identity given $a + b + c = \pi$

Tags: trigonometry, alternative-proof

Given that $a + b + c = \pi$, that is, three angles in a triangle - then prove that $$\tan a + \tan b + \tan c = \tan a \tan b \tan c$$

Is my solution below completely rigorous? Can I justify taking the tangent of both sides of my equation (I think not, since tangent isn't an injective function).

Comment: Any well defined function satisfies $a=b\implies f(a)=f(b)$. Your proof never required injectivity of tangent, which would be the converse of the above statement.

Comment: @boxotimbits I see, that makes sense now. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can write $a + b = \pi -c$ then taking the tangent of both sides, this yields $$\tan (a +b) = \tan(\pi -c) \iff \frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1 - \tan a \tan b} = -\tan c$$

So $$\tan a + \tan b = \tan a \tan b \tan c - \tan c$$

Hence we arrive at $$\bbox[10px, border: blue 1px solid]{\tan a + \tan b + \tan c = \tan a \tan b \tan c} \quad \square$$

as required.

Comment: The given identity doesn't make sense when one of the angles is $\pi/2$. Granted that, the solution is correct, because $\pi-c=a+b\ne\pi/2$.

Comment: @egreg So this identity won't hold for any right-angled triangle, then?

Comment: Neither side makes sense for a right triangle (unless you accept that in this case both sides evaluate $\infty$).

Comment: @egreg, yeah - I get what you mean. I wonder if there's a similar identity involving the two non-pi/2 angles in a right angle triangle... probably not, given that you'd have $a + b = \frac{\pi}{2}$ - perhaps a non-tangent identity...

Comment: If $c=\pi/2$, then $\tan b=\cot a$ or $\tan a\tan b=1$.

Comment: An identity holding for *any* triangle is $\cot a\cot b+\cot a\cot c+\cot b\cot c=1$. For a non right triangle, it is the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Note that; $\tan(a+b+c)=0$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  \frac{\tan(a+b)+\tan(c)}{1-\tan(a+b)\tan(c)} &=& 0 \\\\
  \tan(a+b)+\tan(c) &=& 0 \\\\
   \frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}+\tan(c)&=& 0 \\\\
  \tan(a)+\tan(b)+(1-\tan(a)\tan(b))\tan(c) &=& 0 \\\\
  \tan(a)+\tan(b)+\tan(c)-\tan(a)\tan(b)\tan(c) &=& 0\\\\
\tan(a)+\tan(b)+\tan(c) &=& \tan(a)\tan(b)\tan(c)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Provided none of the angles is $\pi/2$ (but this is implicit in the identity to be proved).

Comment: The original problem say that is a acute triangle

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran The OP doesn't say that. The identity holds for all non-right triangles.

Comment: @user236182 ok thanks